# Finding Factorial with a C Program

Tags: c, recursion

Why is my coding output is 0

I thing my coding is almost right and there is no error in DEVC++ , please help me find the error of my coding

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int);

int main()
{
  int n;

  printf("Enter a number to find it's Factorial: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n < 0)
  {
    printf("Factorial of negative number not possible\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d!=%d\n",n, factorial(n));
  }
  printf("The factorial is %d",factorial(n));
}
int factorial(int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return(n * factorial(n - 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What does your program do to compute factorial(0), which should be 1?

Comment: 1! is not 0....

Comment: Thank You so Much@ UnholySheep@Jens@Olaf

Comment: The title asks about using arrays. Your program doesn't use arrays (and doesn't need them).

Comment: Another problem: You use the `if`/`else` to call `factorial()` only when `n` is greater than or equal to zero. You then call `factorial()` again unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

replace
if(n==1)
return 0;

with
If(n==1 || n==0) 
return 1;

1! is 1.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think happens when you multiply a number with 0? Note that 0! is 1, not 0, and so is 1!.

Take a *very* sharp look at the `return 0;` statement.